# reshaping logits to dim 1

Tags: tensorflow, huggingface-transformers

I am currently working on a T5 model which I am trying to fine-tune. On the training step, I get my outputs, get my loss, and try to update the state of my metric. However, in order to update the state of the metric I am required to use a 1-D array.

From the documentation: "Both
prediction and labels must be 1-D arrays of the same shape in order for this
function to work."

My question is, is there a recommended way to reshape my outputs.logits variable? it currently has a shape of (8, 2, 32128) and would like to bring it 8. I have tried the argmax function, and softmax but had no luck. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Code:

```
model_name = 't5-base'
t5_model = TFT5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_name)
t5_tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)

def train_step(self, inputs):
  input_ids = inputs['input_ids']
  attention_mask = inputs['attention_mask']
  labels = inputs['labels']
  labels_mask = inputs['labels_mask']
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    outputs = self(input_ids=input_ids,
                       attention_mask=attention_mask,
                       labels=labels,
                       decoder_attention_mask=labels_mask,
                       training=True
                  )
    loss = self.compiled_loss(labels, outputs.logits, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    
  self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
  self.compiled_metrics.update_state(labels, outputs.logits) ## issue happens here
  return_metrics = {}
  for metric in self.metrics:
    result = metric.result()
    if isinstance(result, dict):
        return_metrics.update(result)
    else:
        return_metrics[metric.name] = result
  if "loss" in return_metrics and "loss_loss" in return_metrics:
    del return_metrics["loss_loss"]
  return return_metrics
```

Comment: What are your `labels` and how do you initialize `compiled_metrics`?